# jquery clone work the first time but not later

Tags: javascript, jquery

Add row will clone the div but when I continue to click it doesn't clone single element but multiples, what's the flaw of the logic here?

```js
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.elem').clone().appendTo($(this).siblings('.elem'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem">elem</div>
<a id="addRow">+</a>
```

Comment: When you clone `#addRow`, the selector will select all of the ones that exist, including the one you just cloned. So it will double whatever you have.

Comment: @Patosai because of silbings() right? is there any sibling() where it only select one sibling?

Comment: `first()`, see alex's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `.elem` selector matches more and more elements each time you click the button.

A way to resolve this is to keep a reference to one element and use that to clone and then append; additionally, it makes sense to group those elements in another `<div>` for easier reference.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var $elem = $('#rows .elem'); // keep as reference

  $('#addRow').click(function () {
    $('#rows').append($elem.clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rows">
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>
<a id="addRow">+</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to only select *one* element, and the `siblings('.elem')` call is selecting all of them (except the current), including the cloned ones.

You can call `first()` after you call `siblings()` to select only one.

You also probably want to append them to the parent, not the same collection of all siblings.

```
var $clone = $(this).siblings('.elem').first().clone();

$clone.appendTo($(this).parent());
```

Alternatively, you could `insertAfter()` the last element (`$(this).siblings('.elem').last()`).

Answer (score 1):

You are having multiple cloning because each time the element is cloned a new element with `class="elem"` is generated and hence all the elements having `class="elem"` are cloned on each click.

To address this problem use `first()` which only selects the first element with `class="elem"` and thus only one element is cloned on each click.

Below is a simplified version of the code,

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){
    $(".elem").first().clone().appendTo("body");
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle for this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/00Lwnh9v/)

Instead of appending it to "body" use the id of the element to which you want to append the cloned elements. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Clone only the first element and insert it just once, after the last instance.

```js
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.elem:first').clone().insertAfter($(this).siblings('.elem:last'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem">elem</div>
<a id="addRow">+</a>
```